# Includes still result in second database query when using relation with limited columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to use `includes` on a query to limit the number of subsequent database calls that fire when rendering but I also want the include calls to select a subset of columns from the related tables. Specifically, I want to get a set of posts, their comments, and just the name of the user who wrote each comment.

So I added

```
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :user_for_display, :select => "users.id, user.name", :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

to my comments model.

From the console, when I do

```
p = Post.where(:id => 1).includes(comments: [:user_for_display])
```

I see that the correct queries fire:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.id = 1
SELECT comments.* FROM comments comments.attachable_type = "Post" AND comments.attachable_id IN (1)
SELECT users.id, users.name FROM users WHERE users.id IN (1,2,3)
```

but calling

```
p.first.comments.first.user.name
```

still results in a full user load database call:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 11805 LIMIT 1
=> "John"
```

Referencing just `p.first.comments` does not fire a second comments query. And if I include the full `:user` relation instead of `:user_for_display`, the call to get the user name doesn't fire a second users query (but i'd prefer not to be loading the full user record).

Is there anyway to use SELECT to limit fields in an includes?

Comment: Have you tried `p.first.comments.first.user_for_display.name`?

Comment: @Pavan ah, you rock! thanks!

Comment: I will add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query with `user_for_display` instead of `user`.

```
p.first.comments.first.user_for_display.name
```